# how to enqueue 3 work items with different sizes and constraints

Tags: c++, opencl

I would like to have a work group of a framebuffer Width*Height plus a counter that goes from 0 to 18

I tried to set the global work size to 800,800,18,
but get global id number 2 is always zero

```
        global_size[0] = 800;
        global_size[1] = 800;
        global_size[2] = 18;

        local_size[0] = 1;
        local_size[1] = 1;
        local_size[2] = 1;

        err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel_sendImageToPBO, 3, NULL, global_size,
            NULL, 0, NULL, &kernel_event);
        if (err < 0) {
            perror("Couldn't enqueue the kernel");
            exit(1);
        }
```

in kernel

```
int x = get_global_id(0);
int y = get_global_id(1);
int z = get_global_id(2);
printf("%d \r\n", z);
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting `printf` output for *every* work item? With over 11 million work items, many OpenCL implementations will drop a large percentage of submitted `printf` messages. At minimum, make sure the number of outputs you receive does equal 11520000 before suspecting a problem with the OpenCL call.

Comment: (You could, for example, use something like: `if (x < 16 && y < 16 && z > 0) printf("%d\n, z);` to reduce the number of messages and make sure the ones you are interested in won't be dropped.)